# wp_date doesn't work

Tags: date

in my original code the date was wrapped with date_formatted. my website is bilingual so i need to localize date format and name of months etc. i've changed it with wp_date but it does not work.

the original code. the output of date_format is only english so it is not good for me.

```
function getDateSF ( $start, $end ) {

    $_start = [ date_format( $start, __('F d', 'my-theme') ), date_format( $start, __('g:i a', 'my-theme') ) ];
    $_end = [ date_format( $end, __('F d', 'my-theme') ), date_format( $end, __('g:i a', 'my-theme') ) ];

    $date = '<div class="transl">'.$_start[0] .' | '. $_start[1] .'  '. __('to', 'my-theme') .' '. $_end[1] .'</div>';

    if ( date_format( $start, 'Y/m/d' ) != date_format( $end, 'Y/m/d' ) )
        $date = '<div class="transl">'. $_start[0] .' | '. $_start[1] .' </div><div class="transl"> '. $_end[0] .' | '. $_end[1] .'</div>';

    return $date;
}
```

wp_date is good for localization but it doesn't work:

```
function getDateSF ( $start, $end ) {

    $_start = [ wp_date( __('F d', 'my-theme'), $start ), wp_date( __('g:i a', 'my-theme'),  $start ) ];
    $_end = [ wp_date(  __('F d', 'my-theme'),$end ), wp_date(  __('g:i a', 'my-theme'),$end ) ];

    $date = '<div class="transl">'.$_start[0] .' | '. $_start[1] .'  '. __('to', 'my-theme') .' '. $_end[1] .'</div>';

    if ( date_format( $start, 'Y/m/d' ) != date_format( $end, 'Y/m/d' ) )
        $date = '<div class="transl">'. $_start[0] .' | '. $_start[1] .' </div><div class="transl"> '. $_end[0] .' | '. $_end[1] .'</div>';

    return $date;
}
```

**edit**

wp_date only accepts unix timestamp so the solution is wrapping variables like $start and $end with date_timestamp_get().

```
wp_date( __('F d', 'my-theme'),  date_timestamp_get($start)  );
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make my local WP installation display the date in French:

```
switch_to_locale( 'fr_CA' );
echo wp_date( 'F d' );
```

Output: `octobre 11`

(Note that I didn't have to localize my date format string (ie, no `__()` inside the `wp_date()` call.)

However, when I tried Dutch:

```
switch_to_locale( 'nl_NL' );
echo wp_date( 'F d' );
```

Output: `October 11`

This is because the French (`fr_*`) language packs have been installed, but not the Dutch ones (`nl_*`).

Are you *sure* the required language packs are installed on your server? If not, check with your hosting provider.

### References

- [`switch_to_locale()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/)
- [`wp_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/)

Comment: without "__()" it does not work either.

Comment: Are you *sure* the language pack(s) are installed? If they're not, any attempt to switch the locale will fail over to the default (presumably English).

Comment: yep it is installed.  wp_date( 'F d', $start) and others don't work. though i don't get how to update the current code with your solution.

Comment: If you insert `var_dump( get_locale() );` before your code, what locale are you in? If it's `en_{something}` then you need to somehow switch to the desired locale before you use `wp_date()`.